# RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:0 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cpu

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

RuntimeError: module must have its parameters and buffers on device cuda:0 (device_ids[0]) but found one of them on device: cpu.
when i use the remote server to test the BEVDet code, i have meet above question,i have tried all the solutions in the website but cannot useful for me,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtZRs.png)

i have tried the next two

```
device1 = torch.device("cuda:0")
model.to(device1)
```

but not useful.